# How to assign value to multiple member a structure at once

Tags: c, arrays, struct, initialization, compound-literals

Let's assume that we have a struct that has 4x 1-byte members. 
I want to use Xyz as a memory address and cast it as a 32bit pointer then I will assign values to it.
By this, I would able to set all the byte members at once.
This is just an example for my question, char, int, or set to 256 is just arbitrary examples.

```
 #include <stdio.h>

    struct temp{
        char abc;
        char def;
        char ghk;
        char lmn;
    }xyz;

    int main()
    {
        xyz = (struct temp){11,22,33,44};
        printf("Byte1 %d\r\n",xyz.abc);
        printf("Byte2 %d\r\n",xyz.def);
        printf("Byte3 %d\r\n",xyz.ghk);
        printf("Byte4 %d\r\n",xyz.lmn);    
        *((unsigned int*)xyz) = 256;
        printf("Byte1 %d\r\n",xyz.abc);
        printf("Byte2 %d\r\n",xyz.def);
        printf("Byte3 %d\r\n",xyz.ghk);
        printf("Byte4 %d\r\n",xyz.lmn); 
        return 0;
    }
```

Here I prepare a similar approach for the array which is working as expected ;

```
#include <stdio.h>

char mem[4];

int main()
{
    mem[0] = 49;
    mem[1] = 50;
    mem[2] = 51;
    mem[3] = 52;
    printf("Byte1 %d\r\n",mem[0]);
    printf("Byte2 %d\r\n",mem[1]);
    printf("Byte3 %d\r\n",mem[2]);
    printf("Byte4 %d\r\n",mem[3]);    
    *(int*)mem = 256;
    printf("Byte1 %d\r\n",mem[0]);
    printf("Byte2 %d\r\n",mem[1]);
    printf("Byte3 %d\r\n",mem[2]);
    printf("Byte4 %d\r\n",mem[3]);
    return 0;
}
```

How can I do the same thing that I did by an array by using struct?

Comment: Arrays do not have the assignment operator.

Comment: "mem" is the address of the array , I took that address and cast it as integer(4bytes) . This part works like a charm. The problem is only for the struct .

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
*((unsigned int*)xyz) = 256;
```

Is a **strict aliasing violation**.  This means you can't take a pointer to one type, cast it to another type, dereference the casted pointer, and expect things to work.  The only exception is casting to a pointer to `char *` to read the individual bytes of some other type.

What you *can* do however is use a `union`.  It is permitted to write to one member of a `union` and read from another to reinterpret the bytes as a different type.  For example:

```
union u {
    int i;
    struct {
        char c1;
        char c2;
        char c3;
        char c4;
    } s;
};

...

union u u1;
u1.i = 256;
printf("byte1=%02x\n", u1.c1);
printf("byte2=%02x\n", u1.c2);
printf("byte3=%02x\n", u1.c3);
printf("byte4=%02x\n", u1.c4);
```